# Openpyxl: Read-Only mode, How to get Hyperlink

Tags: python, openpyxl

In regular (non read-only mode) I can get a hyperlink from a cell using:

```
if not sheet.cell(row=i_row, column=i_col).hyperlink == None:
    print(cell.hyperlink.location)
```

But when I do it in read only mode, I get the error (Expected):

```
<class 'AttributeError'> 'ReadOnlyCell' object has no attribute 'hyperlink'
```

Is there some way for me to get a hyperlink from a cell in read-only mode?

I have to use read only mode, as I'm trying to parse a secondary sheet (~200 lines) in a workbook where the primary sheet is ~100k lines and I can't keep spending the time loading the entire workbook before processing it. The rest of my code works well with read-only mode.

Open to alternative modules that can solve similar problems. Without RO mode, my code takes 4 seconds per file, with it, 0.25 seconds.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: No. The details for hyperlinks are contained at the bottom of the worksheet file which largely obviates much of the performance advantages of read-only mode.

Comment: This is sad. Given that xlrd has dropped support for xlsx files, I remain in search of a new module.

Comment: I'm facing a similar situation right now. What solution did you settle on in the end?